# How to get accurate figures in the table and show it with the Google Chart API and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

My code **runs** very well with the **whole numbers** as `1000, 1170, 660` and Google Chart API. However, it **didn't work** with the **decimal numbers** as `1000.5, 1170.3, 660.8`, it then **returned** these values back **to** `1000, 1170, 660`. Please let me know what's wrong here.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="chart_div" style="align-content: center"></div>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Title1</td>
        <td>Title2</td>
        <td>Title3</td>
        <td>Title4</td>
        <td>Title5</td>
        <td>Title6</td>
        <td>Title7</td>
        <td>Title8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ms-vb-title">Year</td>
        <td class="ms-vb-title">Year</td>
        <td class="ms-vh2">2004</td>
        <td class="ms-vh2">2005</td>
        <td class="ms-vh2">2006</td>
        <td class="ms-vh2">2007</td>
        <td class="ms-vh2">2008</td>
        <td class="ms-vh2">2009</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ms-vb-title">Sales</td>
        <td class="ms-vb-title">Sales</td>
        <td class="ms-vh2">1000</td>
        <td class="ms-vh2">1170</td>
        <td class="ms-vh2">660</td>
        <td class="ms-vh2">980</td>
        <td class="ms-vh2">1200</td>
        <td class="ms-vh2">1000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ms-vb-title">Expenses</td>
        <td class="ms-vb-title">Expenses</td>
        <td class="ms-vh2">400</td>
        <td class="ms-vh2">460</td>
        <td class="ms-vh2">1120</td>
        <td class="ms-vh2">1220</td>
        <td class="ms-vh2">1180</td>
        <td class="ms-vh2">740</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javacript:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Get data from ? column?
    var from_column = 0;
    // Get data to ? column?
    var to_column = 6;


    var FChartValue1 = new Array();
    var FChartName = new Array();


    $("document").ready(function () {

        var Coords1 = new Array();
        var Coords2 = new Array();
        var Labels = new Array();

        var vertical_axis = "2,3";
        vertical_axis = vertical_axis.split(',');
        for (var i = 0; i < vertical_axis.length; i++) {
            Coords1 = getCoords(vertical_axis[0]); // Display Vertical Axis in the row "2"
            Coords2 = getCoords(vertical_axis[1]); // Display Vertical Axis in the row "3"
        }

        function getCoords(vertical_axis) {
            var Coords = [];
            var arrayList1 = $("td.ms-vb-title:contains('')").eq(1).closest('table').find('tr');
            var arrayList1_temp;
            $(arrayList1).each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('td.ms-vb-title').eq(0).text() != "") {
                    if (arrayList1_temp) {
                        arrayList1_temp = arrayList1_temp.add($(this).find('td.ms-vb-title').eq(1).closest('table').find('tr').eq(vertical_axis).find('td').not(".ms-vb-title").slice(from_column, to_column));
                    }
                    else {
                        arrayList1_temp = $(this).find('td.ms-vb-title').eq(1).closest('table').find('tr').eq(vertical_axis).find('td').not(".ms-vb-title").slice(from_column, to_column);
                    }
                }
            });
            $.each(arrayList1_temp, function (i, e) {
                Coords[i] = $(e).text();
            });
            return Coords;
        }


        var temp = "Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun";
        temp = temp.split(",");
        $.each(temp, function (i) {
            Labels[i] = temp[i];
        });

        FChartValue1 = Coords1; // Display value in the column "1" to the Chart
        FChartValue2 = Coords2; // Display value in the column "2" to the Chart
        FChartName = Labels;
    });


    //Graph Rendering
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        data.addColumn('string', 'Number');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales'); // Annotate P2
        data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses'); // Annotate P3

        data.addRows(FChartValue1.length);

        for (i = 0; i < FChartValue1.length; i++) {
            data.setValue(i, 0, FChartName[i]);
            data.setValue(i, 1, parseInt(FChartValue1[i]));
            data.setValue(i, 2, parseInt(FChartValue2[i]));
            //data.setValue(i, 2, parseInt(FChartValue2[i])); // Second column Chart
        }

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {
            title: 'Report for Electric Energy Consumption', // Title for the Chart
            width: 1000, height: 400, is3D: false,
            hAxis: { title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: { color: 'black', fontName: 'Tahoma', italic: false } }, // Title for Horizontal Axis
            vAxis: { title: "kW", titleTextStyle: { color: 'black', fontName: 'Tahoma', italic: false } }, // Title for Vertical Axis
        }
        );
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data.setValue(i, 1, parseInt(FChartValue1[i]));
data.setValue(i, 2, parseInt(FChartValue2[i]));
```

`parseInt` would need to be `parseFloat` in order to work with decimal numbers.